# Implicit Differentiation of $x^3+y^3=3xy$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

Recently I came across a problem that asked to solve for the derivative of the following equation: $$x^3+y^3=3xy$$

I started by differentiating both sides, and I got $3x^2+3y^2\frac{dy}{dx}$ on the left side. But I cannot figure out out to differentiate $3xy$, because they're being multiplied together. Any help on how to complete the solution and solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$?

Comment: Use $(fg)'=f'g+g'f$.

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Andrei commented, you want to use the product rule:
$$\frac{d}{dx}[xy]=\frac{d}{dx}[x]y+x\frac{d}{dx}[y]=1.y+x.\frac{dy}{dx}=y+x\frac{dy}{dx}$$
see [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule) and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M0SMSWM2oZA) is quite helpful

Comment: I tried this and it worked. I knew what the product rule was, but I never really had to use it before. Thanks a lot.